# How to make a snapshot of a Linux block device

Tags: snapshot

It is well documented how to make snapshots of LVM volumes but how can I make a snapshot of, say, a hard-drive partition? I often wish I can do this when I need to access a disk read-only but there can be reasons to have write access with writes being discarded after the session:

- The application I want to run on the contents of the disk needs to write to it to give access to the data, e.g. the `dovecot` IMAP server updates index files and flags (messages marked as "read" or "important").
- I want to replay the filesystem journal as I know there was an unclean shutdown but I also want to keep the contents unchanged in case I need to explore other data recovery options.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582019/lvm-like-snapshot-on-a-normal-block-device (removed question; relatedness based on question title in URL; I cannot view the question body due to insufficient reputation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low level interface to device mapper can do this:

```
NAME=nameofsnapshot
DEVRO=/dev/read-only-backing-device
DEVCOW=/dev/space-for-writing-changes

SECTORS=$(blockdev --getsz $DEVRO)
TABLE=$(mktemp)

echo 0 $SECTORS snapshot $DEVRO $DEVCOW N 16 >> $TABLE

echo "Setting up $NAME with"
head $TABLE

dmsetup create $NAME < $TABLE

rm $TABLE
```

Explanation of table parameters:

- N = not persistent, will not survive reboot
- 16 = chunk size in sectors for CoW, here 8 KiB

Query status: `dmsetup status $NAME`

Remove snapshot: `dmsetup remove $NAME`

References:

- https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2018-01-25-fun-with-devicemapper-snapshot/
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt

Answer copied from https://gist.github.com/jowagner/b36024636140ddf453c12eaf6e590b5d with permission.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about `blockdev --getsz`!